# Elements tab in Google Chrome DevTools is misbehaving

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have been using google chrome as the primary browser to develop and maintain UIs for multiple websites for a number of years, however, since yesterday, I am now facing an issue with the "Elements" tab in DevTools.

On all websites it works properly, however, on a single website I am working on locally is not showing properly, see screenshot for reference
[image]

I have tried reversing all changes to before it occurred on my website, to make sure it's not from my end,
I have closed and opened the tab,
I have restarted chrome,

ANyone know why this may happen?

Comment: Open devtools settings and click "Restore defaults". If it won't help then reinstall Chrome.

Comment: Restore Defaults worked, even though I never changed any settings. Thanks wOxxOm